# Sending a random token using cookies

Tags: javascript, jsf, cookies

The managed bean :

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Bean() {}

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("token", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        cookie.setMaxAge(-1);
        ((HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse()).addCookie(cookie);
    }
}
```

The cookie named `token` is added to the response in a `@PostConstruct` method.

This cookie is attempted to be accessed by JavaScript as follows.

```
<h:head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var cookie = getCookie("token");
        console.log(cookie);

        function getCookie(name) {
            var matched = document.cookie.match(RegExp(name + "=.[^;]*"));

            if (matched) {
                return matched[0].split('=')[1];
            }

            return false;
        }
    </script>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        #{bean}
    <h:form>
</h:body>
```

It works fine unless the same page is opened almost simultaneously in different tabs and/or windows as happens, when a link corresponding to a page is clicked several times holding the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key in which case the token is shared across different tabs which is expected to be unique across tabs and/or windows.

Using `<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.init}">`, `<f:viewAction action="#{bean.init}">` or a Servlet filer to set the cookie a little earlier makes no difference.

How to make sure that the cookie value is always according to a new generated value in the managed bean and does not collide, when the same page is frequently requested and opened in different tabs and/or windows?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to use an additional cookie for the problem you're trying to solve? Most reliable way would be to just let JSF print the token as if it's a JS variable (or a HTML5 data attribute). But this doesn't involve additional cookies. At most the HTTP session could be used to associate the token with something (the max age of `-1` indicates a session cookie).

Comment: What is the actual non technical usecase?

Comment: It was not a real requirement as of now. It was merely an attempt to see how to notify only a particular tab or window the user is currently on through WebSockets as such an unusual requirement may also arise sometimes. Anyway, I handled it appropriately using a request based token in the form of a hidden form field.